Best way to update depreciated code in FaceRadar Autopsy 4.21.0 Netbeans platform module
I'm having problems updating some depreciated methods, that use the Autopsy Platform.
I'd like a custom attribute under analysis results!
I dislike JavaDoc as it's unwieldy. https://sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/docs/jni-docs/4.12.1/deprecated.html
https://sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/docs/jni-docs/4.12.1//mod_bbpage.html
                BlackboardArtifact artifact = file.newArtifact(BlackboardArtifact.ARTIFACT_TYPE.TSK_INTERESTING_ITEM);
                BlackboardAttribute attribute = new BlackboardAttribute(BlackboardAttribute.ATTRIBUTE_TYPE.TSK_SET_NAME.getTypeID(), PTDetectorIngestModuleFactory.getModuleName(), "PT Detected Faces");
                artifact.addAttribute(attribute);

                // This method is thread-safe with per ingest job reference counted
                // management of shared data.
                addToBlackboardPostCount(context.getJobId(), 1L);

                // Fire an event to notify any listeners for blackboard postings.
                ModuleDataEvent event = new ModuleDataEvent(PTDetectorIngestModuleFactory.getModuleName(), BlackboardArtifact.ARTIFACT_TYPE.TSK_INTERESTING_ITEM);
                IngestServices.getInstance().fireModuleDataEvent(event);

I get the following when I clean and build:
Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\cam30\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FaceRadar-master\build\classes
Ignoring source, target and bootclasspath as release has been set
C:\Users\cam30\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FaceRadar-master\src\com\sazquatch\faceradar\autopsy\FaceRadarFileIngestModule.java:108: warning: [deprecation] TSK_INTERESTING_FILE_HIT in ARTIFACT_TYPE has been deprecated
                BlackboardArtifact artifact = file.newArtifact(BlackboardArtifact.ARTIFACT_TYPE.TSK_INTERESTING_FILE_HIT);
C:\Users\cam30\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FaceRadar-master\src\com\sazquatch\faceradar\autopsy\FaceRadarFileIngestModule.java:108: warning: [deprecation] newArtifact(ARTIFACT_TYPE) in AbstractContent has been deprecated
                BlackboardArtifact artifact = file.newArtifact(BlackboardArtifact.ARTIFACT_TYPE.TSK_INTERESTING_FILE_HIT);
C:\Users\cam30\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FaceRadar-master\src\com\sazquatch\faceradar\autopsy\FaceRadarFileIngestModule.java:109: warning: [deprecation] BlackboardAttribute(int,String,String) in BlackboardAttribute has been deprecated
                BlackboardAttribute attribute = new BlackboardAttribute(BlackboardAttribute.ATTRIBUTE_TYPE.TSK_SET_NAME.getTypeID(), FaceRadarIngestModuleFactory.getModuleName(), "FaceRadar Detected Faces");
C:\Users\cam30\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FaceRadar-master\src\com\sazquatch\faceradar\autopsy\FaceRadarFileIngestModule.java:117: warning: [deprecation] TSK_INTERESTING_FILE_HIT in ARTIFACT_TYPE has been deprecated
                ModuleDataEvent event = new ModuleDataEvent(FaceRadarIngestModuleFactory.getModuleName(), BlackboardArtifact.ARTIFACT_TYPE.TSK_INTERESTING_FILE_HIT);
C:\Users\cam30\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FaceRadar-master\src\com\sazquatch\faceradar\autopsy\FaceRadarFileIngestModule.java:118: warning: [deprecation] fireModuleDataEvent(ModuleDataEvent) in IngestServices has been deprecated
                IngestServices.getInstance().fireModuleDataEvent(event);

